# string to Integer parsing with Exception Handling in Haskell

Tags: haskell

Trying to make type `nat` which return `[ (int, string) ]; handle zero as string`

and type `int` which can handle `negative integer also.`

```
import Data.Char ( isDigit )    

type Parser tok a = [tok] -> [(a, [tok])] 
    
return :: a -> Parser tok a 
return v = \ts -> [(v, ts)]

failure :: Parser tok a 
failure = \_ -> [] 

item :: Parser tok tok 
item []     = []
item (t:ts) = [(t, ts)] 

sat :: (tok -> Bool) -> Parser tok tok 
sat test = item >>= \t -> 
           if test t then return t 
                     else failure 

(<|>) :: Parser tok a -> Parser tok a -> Parser tok a 
p1 <|> p2 = \ts -> case p1 ts of 
                     [] -> p2 ts
                    rs1 -> rs1

many1 :: Parser tok a -> Parser tok [a] 
many  p = many1 p <|> return []
many1 p = p      >>= \v  -> 
          many p >>= \vs -> 
          return (v:vs)

digit = sat isDigit
```

first I make nat and use if ~ then ~ else make exception of 0.

```
nat :: Parser Char Int 
nat = many1 digit >>= \s -> 
      if (s == "0") then failure 
                    else return (read s)
```

It was able to handle one zero.

```
nat "0"
> [] 

nat "0def" 
> []
```

but can't handle when consecutive numbers starting with 0 come to input.

```
nat "012def" 
> [(12, "def")] -- probably my code only handle 1 Zero
-- expect return [] 

nat "000def" 
> [(0, "def")]  -- but i really don't know why this output is coming 
-- expect return []
```

I tried to put aside the problem about nat and make an int first.

first I tried to use nat to define int.

```
int :: Parser Char Int 
int = nat >>= \s -> 
      if (s < 0) then return (-s) 
                 else return s
```

And I realize that i can't make to compiler recognize that s is negative.

so i tried to make it simillar as nat. which I want to add char '-'?

```
int :: Parser Char Int 
int = many1 digit >>= \s -> 
      if (s == "-") then return (read s) ++ "-"  
                    else return (read s)
```

I have two question

1. Why nat only handle 1 zero? I thought many1 is recursive parsing string step-by-step.
2. How can I add "-" in int? does it related with thins like synthetic function?

I am weak at using Haskell. is there something i'm missing?

Comment: Your first question doesn't make sense. `nat` doesn't only handle one zero. It handles all of them.

Comment: @FyodorSoikin nat "012def" return [(12, "def}] . expect retrun []

Comment: Typically, you would define `Parser` as a `newtype`, so that you could define an appropriate `Monad` instance to provide `return`, rather than defining `return` as a regular function. (Similarly for `<|>` in an `Alternative` instance, which would give you `many`, though not `many1`, for free.)

Comment: If you define it as a `newtype Parser tok a = P ([tok] -> [(a, [tok])])` you can derive many of the functions you have via the state transformer on lists: `deriving (Functor, Applicative, Alternative, Monad, MonadState [tok], MonadFail, MonadFix, ..) via StateT [tok] []`

Comment: In `nat "012def"` the `many1 digit` call consumes the first three characters and returns "012". And because `"012" /= "0"`, `nat` does not return a failure.

Comment: It's unclear what you actually want to do. Start with a function `isValidNatString :: String -> Bool` and replace `s == "0"` with `not (isValidNatString s)`. Test this function on fixed inputs and see if it gives the expected result. If you are trying to exclude any redundant representations with leading zeros, your function is `isValidNatString s = s == "0" || null (takeWhile (== '0') c)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't panic. It is not so difficult.

> 1. Why nat only handle 1 zero? I thought many1 is recursive parsing
>    string step-by-step.

You are right `many1 digit` will apply the parser digit on the longer chain possible. This means that when you are parsing `012def` the parsed part is "012" and the remaining is "def". But you are missing where the error is. It is in the following

```
\s -> if (s == "0") then failure 
                    else return (read s)
```

Once, `many1 digit` finish it provides "012" to your function via the bind (`>>=`) and it is process. But "012" is not "0". So the `else` part is applied : `return (read "012")`. The context `"def"` is not modified. So this results to the answer [12,"def"]. As you can see the problem is not the first part of the bind, but the second one. Since you know that you will only get digit (because `many1 digit` can only parse digit), I suggest that you change your binder with

```
let n = read s 
in if n == 0 then failure 
             else n
```

More elegant (monadic) solution are possibles, but this one is probably quite readable and explicit for new haskeller.

> 2. How can I add "-" in int? does it related with thins like synthetic function?

You can't. You want to read a `Char` that cannot be translate as a digit. So you can't read it as digit. This is a simple parsing problem. You have to deal with the `'-'` separately. You can use a choice between two parsers. The first parses the `Char` `'-'` followed by a natural. The second parses only natural. Then translate the result in an `Int`. Take care to not forget the `0`. It can be handle in the first, the second or both. This means that you can't use `nat` in both... or you will have to make a third parser that only parse `0`. So remember that the order is important.

I am pretty sure that can be write this considering the previous work. You already have the digit and the choice combinator. The `char` parser is pretty obvious. You just have to think about it.

Hope this will help.